# Is it necessary to use the ".6" precision specifier when using "%e" in printf?

Tags: c, printf

I got this question on my C programming book:

> Write calls of printf that display a float variable x in the following formats:
>
> b) Exponential notation: right-justified in a field of size 10; six digits after the decimal point.

If I'm right, the answer should be `printf("%10e", x);` because the default precision in the `e` format specifier is 6 decimals after the decimal point (just like the float format specifier). That's why I didn't put a precision `.6` at all.

But the book has a different answer, it says that `printf("%10.6e", x);` is the answer. Is it necessary to write the `.6` precision when using the `e` specifier to represent 6 decimals after the floating point?

Comment: Even if 6 digits is the default, it is always better to specify it so you know what you want to display and someone who read the code also. You do not have to remember what the default value is.

Comment: Did you read [printf(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html) ? Did you compile your C code with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) invoked as `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` ?

Comment: `%10e` and `%10.6e` are equivalent because if the precision is missing, it is treated as being 6.  However, since the exponent is of the form `e+00` (with the sign and at least 2 digits), `%10e` and `%10.6e` both produce at least 12 characters in the output field, or 13 if the value is negative, or 14 if the magnitude of the exponent is larger than 99 (and less than 1000).  Thus, specifying `10` is silly; the output will always be more than 10 characters wide.  You could use `%10.4e` to get a width of 10 for positive values.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it necessary to write the .6 precision when using the e specifier to represent 6 decimals after the floating point?

No, indeed the default precision is 6.